# Customise as_json response in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building rest APIs in ruby

I am using `@object.as_json()` for the response in json format

I am getting stuck in the mid while transfer the data in `as_json`. I need to more customize the response

I am listing what exactly I want and where I am getting stuck

I am using below code

```
@videos = Video.all.map{|m| m.as_json(
  only: [:title],
  method: [:watch_count],
  include: {
    user: {
      only: [:first_name],
      method: [:role] 
    }
  } 
).merge(
    is_upvoted: m.is_upvoted(current_user)
) }
```

But I need to customise it.

1- I need to pass manual key and value (which is not in db) in video and user object, currently it can be possible with video but not with user. It should e possible with parent object and its child associate object. I don't want to to use :method for the same

2-I need to pass parameter in :method, like video model has a method is_upvoted but having a parameter like current user. So I am unable to pass parameter in :method. currently I can do with merge as I am doing but It can not be possible with user object.

3- I need to change key name while use include: {user: {method: []}}.
I need to use key "owner" at the place of "user"

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do `user.as_json` explicitly and merge results afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `JBuilder`, which much more flexible and allow to make all things from your list. Result code will be like this:

```
@videos = JBuilder.encode do |json|
  json.array! Video.all do |video|
    json.(video, :title, :watch_count)
    json.is_upvoted video.is_upvoted(current_user)

    json.owner do
      json.(video.user, :first_name, :role)
      json.field video.user.with_param(some_param)
    end
  end
end
```

You may find details about `JBuilder` in [documentation](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder).